# Showing the existance of the functions $u,v,s,t$ by Implicit function theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am studying from *William Wade's introduction to analysis book the question 11.6.5 at page 434*

**Question:**

The given nonzero numbers $x_0, y_0, u_0, v_0, s_0, t_0$ which is simultanuously equations

(*)$$u^2+sx+ty=0$$
$$v^2+tx+sy=0$$
$$2s^2x+2t^2y-1=0$$
$$s^2x-t^2y=0$$

Prove that there exist the functions $u(x,y), v(x,y), s(x,y), t(x,y)$ and an open ball $B$ containing $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $u,V,s,t$ are continuously differentiable and satisfies (*) on $B$ and such that $u(x_0,y_0)=u_0, v(x_0,y0_)=v_0, s(x_0,y_0)=s_0, t(x_0,y_0)=t_0$

---

**My solution trial:**

Let's define a function 
$$F(x,y,u,v,s,t)=(u^2+sx+ty,v^2+tx+sy, 2s^2x+2t^2y-1,s^2x-t^2y)$$

Let's find the determinant of $F$

$$DF(x,y,u,v,s,t)= \begin{pmatrix} s & t & 2s^2 & s^2 \\ t & s & 2t^2 & -t^2 \\ 2u & 0& 0&0 \\ 0 & 2v & 0&0 \\ x & y & 4sx & 2sx \\ y & x& 4ty & -2ty\end{pmatrix}$$

Since $x,y,s,t,u,v$ are nonzero, $DF\not=0$

Since $Daf$ is nonzero, I can apply to Implicit function theorem so as to show that functions $u,V,s,t$ exists.

But how apply this theorem? Pleae can someone explain This last sentence more? I thought  there but I cannot apply the theorem. Thank you for helping:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your $F$ function as
$$
F(x,y,u,v,s,t)=(F_1(x,y,u,v,s,t), F_2(x,y,u,v,s,t), F_3(x,y,u,v,s,t),F_4(x,y,u,v,s,t))
$$
You must show that the matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{llll}
\dfrac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial F_3}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial F_4}{\partial u}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}&\dfrac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial F_3}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial F_4}{\partial v}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_1}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial F_2}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial F_3}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial F_4}{\partial s}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_1}{\partial t}&\dfrac{\partial F_2}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial F_3}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial F_4}{\partial t}\\
\end{array}\right)
$$
has non-zero determinant, that is. This is the necessary condition for the Implicit Function Theorem, and guarantees that there is a neigborhood U of $(x_0,y_0)$ where you can write
$$
u=u(x,y),v=v(x,y),s=s(x,y),t=t(x,y)
$$
such that
$$
F(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y),s(x,y),t(x,y))=0
$$

---

Notice that this is a submatrix of the Jacobian matrix you wrote in your question. The trick of the Implicit Function Theorem is, if your function is $F:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, finding the $m\times m$ submatrix of the Jacobian matrix of $F$ (which is $m\times (m+n)$) that corresponds the derivations of the $m$ $F_i$ functions with respect to the variables that you want to become functions (in your case, $(u,v,s,t)$), and looking if it has non-zero determinant.

Phew!

Comment: That's, Is the matrix I wrote above false?

Comment: Or, after the point I come, Will I do what you say?

Comment: If you mean the Jacobian matrix of F, it is correct but it is not what you want in order to use the Implicit Function Theorem. I will add some hint in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I confused. I am happy to expand your answer. :) because I want to learn properly. Thank you:)

Comment: By the way, how Will I find your matrix with these equations?

Comment: which matrix do you mean?

Comment: You wrote as a hint.

Comment: That's by using these equations, I found jacobian matrix. But how can I find the matrix you wrote on answer box with using equations?

Comment: Just use the functions you gave me and calculate the derivatives.

Comment: I understand to calculate its derivatives. But why be given these equations? Sorry, I see your answer style for such questions first time. Thus, I am asking nonsense questions.

Comment: You're not asking nonsense :-) Are you asking why I chose that matrix instead of any other?

Comment: I'm sorry @B11b I was editting my answer and noticed my mistake. I'll correct it.

Comment: I have editted my matrix to match yours; mine was the transpose. No real problem though.

Comment: Okay, now everything clarified. Sorry, I exhaust you with my questions. A successful work in my sight thank you so much:)

Comment: It was no bother; I just got confused with the theorem and the TeX formatting :)

Comment: Yes, of course!you saw/determined my trouble perfectly:)

Comment: I had the same difficulty when learning this.

Comment: Hmm.. But you learnt well, and so, teach perfect. :)

Comment: Thank you! :) You are very kind.

Comment: You're welcome! You too:)